# Can css images load even if they're not applied on a page?

Tags: css, image

After analyzing my site with the [websiteoptimization.com tool](http://websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze), I see that it lists every single css background image, even if they're not applied to any element on the specific page. Is this a bug on their end, or will some browsers load every css image, even if the element they're applied to isn't on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, browsers do not automatically load all images. However if you want that you could "link" them from your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this issue with a tool like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It will show you all the http requests browser makes.